# convert all int type values to strings in a json object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object with the following structure of repeating dictionaries. I want to replace the type values of id, which are all stored as type integer with a string type value. So in the following example, I want to replace the value of id from 1998459 to "1998459".

At the moment, these int-type values are giving me a JSON decode errors when I try to read in this json using json.loads
The error looks like this

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
```

So far I was trying to Find and Replace the int types with String types in atom IDE but I have found no clear solution to do it that way. I am not sure if there is a library I should use or another avenue I should take.

The JSON sample looks like this

```
{  "data": {
"imageData": {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1998459,
      "url": "https:some_url",
      "isInspirational": "true",
      "classifications": [
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Scene",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Contemporary",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Rectangle",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Square",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Trapezoid",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Triangle",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Hard",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Soft",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Smooth",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Stripe",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Primary_Color",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Calm",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Light",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Interior",
        },
        {
          "categoryLabel": "Residential",
        }
      ]
    }          ]
    }
  ]
}  }}
```

Comment: Please add what you have try

Comment: just made an edit. Hopefully it adds more context

Comment: This snippet is not in a valid JSON format.

Comment: JSON should not have leading comma(",")

Comment: just updated the JSON to full file.

Comment: @sanster9292 JSON Does not like trailing commas after the last item in a list or dictionary, for instance the command after "Scene" in  `{"categoryLabel": "Scene",}`

Comment: this JSON formatter/validator might help [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: aha yes i see it now. These files are a mess. lol

Comment: As mentioned, JSON doesn't allow trailing commas. But Python does. You could potentially parse this with `ast.literal_eval` ... except that you have mismatched brackets later on.

Comment: Thank you everyone, the JSON validator helped fix it